# From cmd, log into Bash and run command in one line

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, scp, cmd

I am developing a TIBCO application and need to be able to run a scp command from an external command resource.

Anyway the issue boils down to being able to log in to bash.exe then run my scp command in the same line.

it works when I run (from cmd.exe)

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login
```

(I enter bash)

Then I can run my scp statement just fine

```
scp account@server:~mysourcedirectory/targetfilename* /cygdrive/c/targetfolder
```

I want to do these two things in the same line but it doesnt work, aka

```
 c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -c scp account@server:~mysourcedirectory/targetfilename* /cygdrive/c/targetfolder
```

will fail. What am I doing wrong and how can i run this command in one go?

Thanks

Comment: in windows you can connect multiple commands by the && combination, eg 
"echo hello && pause", I don't know if it works for unix systems. You can give it a try.

Comment: @GamErix, yes it works in bash also.

Comment: You have to quote the command, though I don't know how cmd deals with quotes.

`c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -c 'scp account@server:~mysourcedirectory/targetfilename* /cygdrive/c/targetfolder'`

Comment: Where do you think cmd got the idea for && from. It was the original unix shell sh, written in 1960s. But && has nothing to do with the answer to this question, as there is only one command (plus subcommand).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to quote the command.

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -c "scp account@server:~mysourcedirectory/targetfilename* /cygdrive/c/targetfolder"
```

Tested using cmd in wine in gnu/linux. Single quotes did not work, I don't know all the quoting rules for cmd. But the above did work.